# Aptana Studio 3 (Linux Standalone version) keeps crashing after upgrade to the latest version

Tags: crash, aptana, aptana3

Aptana Studio 3 3.0.9.201202141038-14022012104032

Is there a way to downgrade to the last version I had which is 33.0.8.201201201658-20012012170258 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start here with sending the error-message while crashing.

You can start eclipse from shell (post that backtrace here)
And you can show the eclipseworkspace/.metadata/.log

Answer (score 0):

in most cases this is a memory limits, check this:
[http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?)